# Office 365 email background image/gradient or VML tile/gradient

Tags: html, css, email, office365, vml

EmailOnAcid code analysis for Office 365 says there is no support for background images, in either the shorthand (`background: url("foo.png");`) or explicit (`background-image: url("foo.png");`) format, and no support for the background attribute on `TD` elements either. In addition to these styles, I have VML code targeted to `[if gte mso 9]`.

In some of my tests, I see my background image, but not when I switched from an image/VML tile to a linear gradient/VML gradient. Is this an issue of Office 365 adding image support of some kind recently, or is it that VML gradients are unsupported in Office 365?

**Email code with image:** (note: shown here with `cid` references for attached image; test results were mostly using an image hosted on imgr.com)

```
<head>
  <style>
    table.with-bg {
      width: 570px;
      min-height: 717px;
    }

    table.with-bg td.image-container {
      padding: 10px;
      background: url("cid:mailing_footer") repeat-x;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body link="#497cbe" vlink="#497cbe" alink="#497cbe">
  <table class="with-bg" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="570" height="717">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="image-container" background="cid:mailing_footer" bgcolor="transparent" valign="top" width="570" height="717">
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
          <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:570px;height:717px;">
            <v:fill type="tile" src="cid:mailing_footer" color="#ffffff" />
            <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
          <![endif]-->
          <div>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="570" style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="550">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td colspan="2" align="left" bgcolor="transparent">
                            &nbsp; 
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="transparent"><img id="headerpic" src="cid:mailing_header" width="468" height="71" alt=" " title=" " style="width:468px; height: 71px;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr> 
                          <td colspan="2" class="body" style="min-height:200px;">
                            CONTENT GOES HERE
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                  <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </v:textbox>
          </v:rect>
          <![endif]-->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

**Changed for gradient:**

```
<head>
  <style>
    ...

    table.with-bg td.image-container {
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: white;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #b6cae8, #ffffff);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #b6cae8, #ffffff);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #b6cae8, #ffffff);  
      background-image: linear-gradient(#b6cae8, white);
      background: linear-gradient(#b6cae8, white);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body link="#497cbe" vlink="#497cbe" alink="#497cbe">
    ...
        <td class="image-container" background="linear-gradient(#b6cae8, white);" bgcolor="transparent" valign="top" width="570" style="background-color: white; background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #b6cae8, #ffffff); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #b6cae8, #ffffff); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #b6cae8, #ffffff);  background-image: linear-gradient(#b6cae8, white); background: linear-gradient(#b6cae8, white);">
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
          <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:570px;">
            <v:fill type="gradient" color="#ffffff" color2="#b6cae8" />
            <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
          <![endif]-->
    ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having also brought this up directly with Email On Acid, they responded that Office 365 seems to have added support for the TD background attribute, and they have updated the code analysis to reflect that.

Gradients do not appear to be supported at this time, nor do CID image paths. Absolute URLs for images work, e.g., `<td background="http://foo.com/bar.jpg">`. When running a manual test on EOA via ZIP file upload, relative paths also worked (`<td background="bar.jpg">`), although it's not clear to me if/how that would work in an email sent normally.

**NOTE:** Office 365 and OWA don't use VML, and more importantly, they don't match the `mso` conditional comments!